# LinQ how to improve using CompiledQuery

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a Linq Like this

```
from item in db.SportsActivities where item.GeoSportsId == SportsId select item.SportsTeam)
                        .OrderBy(it => it.Description)
                        .ToList()
                        .ConvertAll<SportsTeam>(ConvertFromDAL)
```

This query is quite inefficient, I'm looking for a way to  optimize it with `CompiledQuery`.
I tried to use this by compiled query though I could not find a way to figure how to arrange and use this with `CompiledQuery`. I'm quite new with LINQ.

Comment: Is this Linq2Sql or Entity Framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Linq2SQL simple queries to CompiledQueries to increase app performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135031/converting-linq2sql-simple-queries-to-compiledqueries-to-increase-app-performanc)

Comment: @ErikPhilips, hi this is not about converting linq to sql simple queries

Comment: No idea what Convert all is, but not sure why you'd want to call `ToList` before it